# Find set of all real such that Endomorphism is an Automorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel like this question should be simple and I must be missing something...

**Question:** Find the set of all real numbers *a* such that the endomorphism of $\Bbb R^3$ represented by the matrix $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & a & a \\
        2 & 2a & 4 \\
        3 & a & 6 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
with respect to the canonical basis is an automorphism.

---

I know that an endomorphism is a linear transformation from an object to itself and that an automorphism is a bijective enodmorphism (onto and one-to-one). However, I have no idea how to solve this problem any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its an automorphism iff the matrix is invertible. What criteria do you know to test if a matrix is invertible?

Comment: @arkeet A matrix is invertible if its determinant is not equal to zero, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are asking you to find $a $ such that the determinant is not zero.

Comment: How do I know from the question that that is what I need to find?

Comment: As you said yourself, you are looking for bijective linear maps. It is key here to understand the relationship between linear operators and matrices.